# MouseMotionListener is not working with Canvas

Tags: java, mousemotionlistener

This is my code so far, what I want to do is to add a new Object every time the mouse is moved, but the system is not even accessing the MouseEvent class after hours of thinking, I still am not able to figure the problem. Please Help!!

My main class:

```
  package testing;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

public class Wincall extends Canvas implements Runnable {

public static final int HEIGHT = 640, WIDTH = 1080;

private WinTest w;              
private Handler handler;
private ME me = new ME(this);

public Wincall(){

    handler = new Handler();
    w = new WinTest(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test", this);

}

public synchronized void run(){

    while(true){

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        this.tick();  
        this.render();

        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int tt = (int) (after-now);
        if(tt>5)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.println("Time Taken in millisecs : " + tt);

    }

}

public void tick(){
    handler.tick();
}

public void render(){

    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    //render

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0 ,0 ,WIDTH, HEIGHT);


    handler.render(g);

    //render end

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public void addStuff(){

    handler.addObject(new TestGO(me.getX(), me.getY(), 32, 32));

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Wincall();
}
  }
```

My MouseEvent class:

```
package testing;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class ME implements MouseMotionListener{

private int mx = 0, my = 0;
private Wincall game;

public ME(Wincall game){
    this.game = game;
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    game.addStuff();
    mx = e.getX();
    my = e.getY();

    System.out.println(mx);
    System.out.println(my);

}

public int getX(){
    return mx;
}

public int getY(){
    return my;
}

}
```

My window class:

```
package testing;

import java.awt.Canvas;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class WinTest {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -369751247370351003L;

public WinTest(int h, int w, String title, Wincall game){

    JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(h, w);
    f.add(game);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.requestFocus();
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setFocusable(true);

    game.addMouseMotionListener(new ME());

    game.run();
}

}
```

Comment: what the `Handler handler` is?

Comment: Handler is a linkedlist for all objects

Comment: whats is the purpose of implementing `wincall` with canvas ? You already have Wintest as canvas. Why are you not using `WinTest` itself ?

Comment: i want to have a separate class for the Window and i will remove implementation of Canvas with Wintest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though its not clear what you are trying to do. But you need to add the `MouseMotionListener` to canvas not to the `JFrame`. Since you are adding canvas to the `JFrame`, it is the `canvas` which should capture MouseEvents. Hence, your `Wintest` should probably look like this :

```
public class WinTest extends Canvas {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -369751247370351003L;

public WinTest(int h, int w, String title, Wincall game, ME me) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(h, w);
    f.add(game);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.requestFocus();
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setFocusable(true);
    // f.addMouseMotionListener(me);
    game.addMouseMotionListener(me);
    game.run();
 }
}
```

Update :

Wincalll Class:

```
public class Wincall extends Canvas implements Runnable {

public static final int HEIGHT = 640, WIDTH = 1080;

private WinTest w;
// private Handler handler;
private ME me = new ME(this);

public Wincall() {

    // handler = new Handler();
    w = new WinTest(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test", this, me);

}

public synchronized void run() {

    while (true) {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        this.tick();
        this.render();

        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int tt = (int) (after - now);
        if (tt > 5)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        // System.out.println("Time Taken in millisecs : " + tt);

    }

}

public void tick() {
    // handler.tick();
}

public void render() {

    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    // render

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // handler.render(g);

    // render end

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public void addStuff() {
    System.out.println("addStuff");
    // handler.addObject(new TestGO(me.getX(), me.getY(), 32, 32));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Wincall();
}
}
```

Comment: this is what i got : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
 at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Component.java:3998)
 at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:3972)
 at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Component.java:4495)
 at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3849)
 at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:194)
 at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Component.java:3773)
 at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Canvas.java:169)

Comment: have you updated your code or Is it the same class(Wintest) you are running because it works for me ? Please post your updated code.I had also changed the `Thread.sleep(1000)` to 1 sec.

Comment: Then it becomes a different issue now, which is related to `Thread`. Earlier you are attaching the `MouseListener` at the wrong place, for which I suggested you a solution. You can track your mouse in the `System.out.println()` and I don't know what you have changed. Also, You didn't provide handler class. We have no idea what you are doing inside that.

Comment: The thing is i can't track my mouse.It is not printing anything, I don't know why. I tried adding the canvas first and then the game object(into the frame), There was a small extra space about a cm or so where the mouselistener would respond, but where the BufferStrategy is acting is not printing out anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at some of my old source codes:

Try

addMouseMotionListener(me);

Instead of:

f.addMouseMotionListener(me);